# flowplayer 200 stream not found on firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, video-streaming, flv, flowplayer

Hello I'd like to use flowplayer on a website but I experienced that it is not relieable with my configurations yet.

Using firefox I sometimes got the error 200 stream not found. It seemed as if the url of the clip has not been passed to the player.

using seamonkey the video was played with the configuration in the example bellow all the time propperly.

using epiphany i only get a black screen which might depend on my css.

but now the real problem and question: why do I get the 200 stream not found problem on firefox and how to get rid of it 100%
do you have it too?

here is a demo page: http://lehrer-beraten-eltern.de/debug

Answer (score 2):

I also received the 200 error when trying to add a video to a site through flow player. There were 2 different things that were causing this. The first was my bucket name was not all lowercase. The second was not including the full file path to the file in the embed source. I haven't encountered any errors that were browser specific regarding using flow player.

Comment: I just added a link bellow all videos which points to the flv file just in case the user is not able to view the video.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time on trying to solve this issue, pulling my hair out !!!

If you can reproduce the problem with other videos, the problem is coming from a bug of Adobe Flash Player 11.

There is a bug in new versions of Adobe Flash Player 
//bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3117684.

The temporary workaround is to [downgrade to 11.1.102.55](http://www.bestkicker.com/forum/13-annonces-officielles/30403-incompatibilite-firefox-adobe-flash-player-111-streaming-video-rtmp.html).

Does it help you ?

Comment: For your information, I tested the beta version 11.3 of Adobe Flash Player and it finally correct the bug :)